# Finding the crosses between two arrays, one sorted, one unsorted

Tags: sorting, big-o

Suppose I write the numbers 1 to n across the page.  Below that I write the numbers in the range 1 ... n in random order across the page. For each i, draw a straight line between i in the top row and the ith smallest number in the bottom row.

Let’s  use C(s)  to  denote  the  number  of crosses for random sequences (of the arrangement of the bottom numbers).

Examples with where C(s) = 3:

```
1    2   3
  \  |  /
    \ /
   / |\
 /   |  \
7    5   1
```

[Linked Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQHI9.png)

1. What are the minimum and maximum values for C(s) in terms of n?  Explain your answers.
2. Create an O(nlgn) algorithm to compute C(s) when given the random sequences.  Justify the running time and correctness of your answer.

**My Answer**

Part one is very easy, 0 is the min value (no crosses with bottom is in a sorted order from least to greatest), and n(n-1)/2 is the max value (where the bottom is in a sorted order from greatest to least).

Part two is where I am struggling, since we are looking for nlgn this seems like it will be a divide and conquer algorithm. However, I am really stumped on how to approach this problem.

Comment: This is not at all related to a programming language, thus I removed the "java" tag. Please only use tags that are relevant to the question.

Comment: What do you call "the number of crossing lines"? Is it the number of crossings? Or the number of lines?

Comment: The question is unclear. Your image does not match your specification, assuming `n=3`. You are using the term "random sequence", but this is not referring to anything in the specification before. Please define the "number of crossing lines". It's unclear why the number of crossing lines can be O(n^2) when you only have n lines.

Comment: In your image, you are counting the number of crossings, but not the number of crossing lines. The number of crossings is not determined by the sequence of number below - it also depends on the exact horizontal positioning of the numbers. Are you sure you didn't misunderstand the task?

Comment: Sorry! fixed the wording should be clearer now.

Comment: It's still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would look something like this:

```
ALGORITHM(Start, End)
   Mid = (Start+End)/2
   If Start <= End-1 : //if number Start and number End are consecutive
      Return (Number of line crossings between Start and End)
   Else
      Find number of line crossings between number Mid and Mid+1 and store in N
   Return( N + ALGORITHM(Start, Mid) + ALGORITHM(Mid+1, End)) //recursive call
```